# Conditional action for 'before_update' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to call the `update` action only if certain condition or a method returns `true` while updating the DB. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
before_update :check_loan_status ,if: ->{}
```

The `update` method will be called even if the conditional statement returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :call_me,:if => Proc.new { |obj| obj.id == obj.id }
  before_update :call_me,:if => Proc.new { |obj| obj.id == obj.id }

  def call_me
    puts "condition is true"
  end
end
```

Comment: you should probably use the syntax 'after_update :call_me, if: Proc.new...' colon instead of fat arrow.

Comment: @xploshioOn colon might not work with old versions of Ruby while fat arrow will work with most versions(probably all). So, When I'm not sure what Ruby version the other person is using, I suggest using the fat arrow.

Comment: you are right, let's be more specific then, if you are usin ruby 1.9 or greater, use colon instead of fat arrow.

Comment: @xploshioOn But let's not be overly dramatic over fat arrow vs colon.

Comment: @xploshioOn I worked with Mongoid a lot and Band.where(:fans.gt => 100000) will work while Band.where(fans.gt: 100000) wont work.

Comment: @xploshioOn So it boils down to your personal preference.

Comment: it's not. when you do this :foo => "content" is the same as foo: "content". but a shorthand to this. and the community is moving to it in general. of course there are no differences. but is shorter and good to read. and there will be parts where you need to use fat arrow, but are just specific cases.